# массив int с рекурсией пошагово в idea вижу как меняются местами числа. но в ИТОГЕ середина без изменений

Tags: java

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

 public static void foo2(int [] arr) {
        if (arr.length <= 1) return;
        else {
            swap(arr);
            if (arr.length>=2)
            foo2( Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length-1));

        }
    }
    private static int[] swap(int[] arr) {
        int tmp = arr[0];
        arr[0]=arr[arr.length-1];
        arr[arr.length-1] = tmp;
        return arr;
    }
```

тогда как похожие действия например сумма работает

```
 public static int sum(int[] array) {
        if (array.length==0)
            return 0;
        else return array[0]+sum(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length));

    }
```

и я могу сделать так: Это работает. ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО ХОЧУ ИЗБАВИТЬСЯ ОТ второго параметра в методе ниже.

```
public static void reverse(int[] arr, int k) {
        if (k < arr.length / 2) {
            int tmp = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[arr.length - 1 - k];
            arr[arr.length - 1 - k] = tmp;
            reverse(arr, k + 1);
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: почему не получается с Arrays.copyOfRange задать границы ? в сумме то работает
ps. догадываюсь что все последующие свопы работают над новыми объектами (которые создаются в новом месте памяти heap'e ? т.к. наблюдая пошагово как идет реверс - после последней операции вижу в sout  6 2345 1, а не 654321 - ), а не над оригиналом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, вы правильно догадываетесь. После первой итерации foo2() работает уже с уменьшенной копией массива и соответственно все изменения в этой копии никоим образом не отражаются на оригинале. Если вас напрягает второй параметр в методе, то можете, к примеру, возвращать изменённый массив

```
    public static int[] foo2(int[] arr) {
        if (arr.length > 1) {
            swap(arr);
            System.arraycopy(foo2(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length - 1)),
                             0, arr, 1, arr.length - 2);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```